# Upload Codable Struct to Firebase Database in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, codable

I am trying to upload some data into my Firebase Realtime Database but got this error while trying to upload the data: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidFirebaseData', reason: '(updateChildValues:) Cannot store object of type __SwiftValue at . Can only store objects of type NSNumber, NSString, NSDictionary, and NSArray.'`

Is there a way to easily upload my codable struct to my DB?

```
func uploadMerchOrder(orderNo: String, email: String?, totalAmount: Int, usingCard: Bool, lineItems: [PrintifyLineItems], address: PrintifyAddress) {
    guard let user = AuthService.shared.user else { return }
    
    let values: [String: Any] = [
        "userID": user.id,
        "email": email ?? user.email,
        "orderID": orderNo,
        "totalAmount": totalAmount,
        "usingCard": usingCard,
        "items": lineItems,
        "address": address
    ]
    
    merchOrders.child(orderNo).updateChildValues(values)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your lineItems and address values are not of a type that can be stored in the Firebase Realtime Database. The Firebase Realtime Database can only store values that are one of the following types: NSNumber, NSString, NSDictionary, or NSArray.

You can fix this issue by encoding your lineItems and address values as dictionaries before passing them to the updateChildValues(_:) method. You can use the JSONEncoder class to encode your values as dictionaries, like this:

```
let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()

let lineItemsData = try jsonEncoder.encode(lineItems)
let lineItemsDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: lineItemsData, options: []) as? [String: Any]

let addressData = try jsonEncoder.encode(address)
let addressDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: addressData, options: []) as? [String: Any]

let values: [String: Any] = [
    "userID": user.id,
    "email": email ?? user.email,
    "orderID": orderNo,
    "totalAmount": totalAmount,
    "usingCard": usingCard,
    "items": lineItemsDict,
    "address": addressDict
]

merchOrders.child(orderNo).updateChildValues(values)
```

This will encode your lineItems and address values as dictionaries and then pass them to the updateChildValues(_:) method, which should fix the error you are seeing.